# Python programming question - numbers and integers and division

Tags: python

**Divisible challenge**

> Write a program that asks the user for two numbers.  The program should output whether the two numbers are exactly divisible by each other.  If not, it should return the remainder.  If the user enters a 0 the program should give an error message.

so far I've done this:

```
num1 = int(input("Enter a number:  "))
num2 = int(input("Enter a number:  "))

answer1 = num1/num2 
answer2 = num2/num1 

if num1/num2 == answer1(int) or num2/num1 == answer2(int):  
    print("Exactly divisible")
elif num1 == 0 or num2 == 0:
    print("Error: you cannot divide by 0")
elif num1/num2 != answer1(int) or num2/num1 != answer2(int): 
    print("Not Exactly divisible")
```

please help...

Comment: Use `%` to tell if numbers are divisible.

Comment: What do you expect `answer1(int)` to be doing exactly? Do you mean `if isinstance(answer1, int)`?

Comment: What is `answer1(int)` supposed to be? I think you mean `int(answer1)`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236. If you have multiple questions at this introductory level, please consider following a tutorial first. If you are already working through a guided course, and have a problem with an assignment (what this appears to be), please first try to ask for help from your instructor. But regardless, we cannot help you if your only request is "please help" - we need a clear, specific question. Right now, we don't know why you can't solve the problem yourself. ("I'm a beginner" is **not** an explanation.)

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this way
first check the zero case, in that case the code terminates faster

```
num1 = int(input("Enter a number:  "))
num2 = int(input("Enter a number:  "))

# answer1 = num1/num2 
# answer2 = num2/num1 

def divisible_by_each_other(num1, num2):
    if (num1 == 0) or (num2==0):
        print("Error do not enter 0")
    #check divisibility
    elif (num1%num2 == 0 ) or (num2%num1 == 0 ):
        print("Exactly divisible")
    else:
        print("Not Exactly divisible")
        high,low= max(num1,num2),min(num1,num2)
        print("The remainder is ", high%low)

divisible_by_each_other(num1, num2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`answer1(int)` is not the correct way to convert to an integer, it's `int(answer1)`.

Since you already divided the numbers, you could use

```
if answer1 == int(answer1) or answer2 == int(answer2):
```

But you're making this much more complicated than it needs to be. Modulus is a simpler way to test divisibility.

```
if num1 % num2 == 0 or num2 % num1 == 0
```

You also should check if either of the numbers is zero *before* you try to use division or modulus. Otherwise, you'll get an error due to trying to divide by 0, which is what you're trying to prevent with this check.

If they're not divisible by each other, get the remainder of the larger divided by the smaller:

```
else:
    return max(num1, num2) % min(num1, num2)
```

Here's the full, simplified code:

```
num1 = int(input("Enter a number:  "))
num2 = int(input("Enter a number:  "))

higher = max(num1, num2)
lower = min(num1, num2)

if num1 == 0 or num2 == 0:
    print("Error: you cannot divide by 0")
elif higher % lower == 0
    print("Exactly divisible")
else:
    print(higher % lower)
```

Comment: I think you should also check which is the larger

Comment: @DrBwts Why is that necessary? `smaller % larger` will never be 0.

Comment: I didn't notice the part that says to return the remainder in the last case.